# How can we manage global state of react application using hooks without using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have been using redux for all of my react projects to maintain global state of application. I read we can manage app's global state using hooks as well without need for redux, but I cant figure out how to use it. Any help or example for doing it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hooks is a functional programming way of doing away with classes in react. However, you can look at **React Context API**. It allows global state management in a react way.

Please note that Recat Context is not a replacement for Redux. They both complement each other, where redux uses this context too.

`const UserContext = React.createContext(null) ;`//default val

the value once you get it you can store any object or functions inside. 
Thus, at the root or app, create a normal global state.

`const [user, setUser] = useState()`
`<UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
       <ComponentA />
     <UserContext.Provider>`

Now the user and the way to user is managed globally throughout application.

Now you iu can use, `const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext)`.

When you invoke setUser, you are now updating global state. Read on to know when to use. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace `Redux` with `ReactHooks`, you can follow with this tutorial: [Link](https://medium.com/octopus-labs-london/replacing-redux-with-react-hooks-and-context-part-1-11b72ffdb533)

> **[Do React Hooks Replace Redux?](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/do-react-hooks-replace-redux-210bab340672)**
>   *TL;DR: Hooks are Great, but No.*

Since the React hooks API was introduced, a lot of questions have risen about whether or not React hooks will replace Redux.

In my view, there is little overlap between `ReactHooks` and `Redux`. Hooks didn’t give us magical new state capabilities. Instead, it enhanced the API for things we could already do with React.

To understand about *what is redux ?*, *what is react hooks?*, *why we might consider Redux in the first place ?*, visit [Here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/do-react-hooks-replace-redux-210bab340672)